# How do you time travel across groups of tables in delta/iceberg?

Tags: delta-lake, apache-iceberg, lance

I am new to these table formats that allow time travel (Dela/iceberg/lance), but it's unclear to me how to manage dependencies across tables.

Suppose you have tables A, B, and C, where C builds on B which builds on A.

A -> B -> C

What are some good patterns to check what version of A generated C?

I could look at the timestamps of the versions, but you quickly end on checking that the timestamps be increasing in complicated ways.

I looked to see what is the minimum version of A that generates a monotonic increasing version timestamp up to C

Comment: "I looked to see what is the minimum version of A that generates a monotonic increasing version timestamp up to C"
Could you please explain what do you mean by this?

Comment: Say I have table A updated at 9am, 10am, 11am, and 12am

Table B updated at 9:30, 9:45, 9:50, 10:20, and 12:15am

Table C updated at 10:15

Then probably table C updated using the 9:50am version of table B, which used the 9am version of table A. So although table A updated at 10, the 10:15 update of table C is probably in reference to the 9am version of table A.

You can see how this gets tricky with 300+ tables

Answer (score 0):

Iceberg does provide time-travel by basically using the snapshots of the table as long as that snapshot exist in the system and data files related to these snapshots exist. There are basically two ways to do time travel.

1. `FOR VERSION AS OF` syntax where you can pass the `snapshot_id`. Snapshot ID is stored in `snaphots` metadata table

```
SELECT * FROM prod.db.table VERSION AS OF 10963874102873;
```

2. `FOR TIMESTAMP AS OF` syntax where you can pass the timestamp at which how the data was.

   SELECT * FROM prod.db.table TIMESTAMP AS OF '1986-10-26 01:21:00';

Comment: Thank you, but not quite the issue I have. It's more about how to time travel across a group of tables using logical version - not timestamp. Say, if table B is built on Monday using Sunday's version of table A... How do you time travel across data pipelines to have a consistent collection of raw and derived tables.

Comment: @MYK you need to maintain this somewhere say on Monday what was the snapshot that was created for tableA and what was the snapshot created for tableB. One way to do it is using `snapshots` metadata table which keeps tracks of all the snapshots and when that snapshot has been created. So if you know the timestamp when your table was updated, you can use metadata table to get snapshot IDs.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll basically propagate some form of metadata across the pipeline to track this. It's a good idea. Say, when the job loads table A to materialize table B it will write as a metadata entry on table B the version of table A that was used.

Comment: So if I have to debug table B, i know what version of table A to load. 

All the more important when you have a 500+ table DAG with multiple inputs to each materialization, and various subsets of the tables running on various schedules (+retries!)